# By using query, how do I create a table in a database instead of a schema in SSMS

Tags: mysql, ssms

I know using the `CREATE TABLE [example_schema].[example table]` creates the table in the schema but I want to create the table in a database instead, but I don't know the syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Royal_Poly_DB.staff_relation (


"staff_no" CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  "staff_name" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  "supervisor" CHAR(4) NULL,
  "dob" DATE NOT NULL,
  "grade" CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  "marital_status" CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  "pay" DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
  "allowance" DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
  "hourly_rate" DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
  "gender" CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  "citizenship" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  "join_yr" INT NOT NULL,
  "dept_cd" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  "type_of_employment" CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  "highest_qln" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  "designation" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (staff_no))
```

Comment: just issue a use <database> before the create - or are you expecting that the db can be created by a create table?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the database in the object explorer and select 
"New Query" then add in you code there

Comment: Seriously this was a question on how to use ssms?